# JQuery select tr elements without a class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following HTML code:

```
   <tr class="rowMain"></tr>  --> if I click on this I should get the 2 <tr> below
   <tr></tr>
   <tr></tr>
   <tr class="rowMain"></tr> --> if I click on this I should get the 3 <tr> below
   <tr></tr>
   <tr></tr>
   <tr></tr>
```

and so on

What I want to select is the `<tr>` elements that are between each rowMain class? what is the best way

I tried the following code in JQuery:

```
$('.main').click(function(){
    $(this).nextAll('tr').not('.rowMain');
});
```

But this is selecting All  element after the click element what is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$('.rowMain').click(function(){
    $(this).nextUntil('.rowMain', 'tr').hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr class="rowMain"><td>test</td></tr>
   <tr><td>1</td></tr>
   <tr><td>1</td></tr>
   <tr class="rowMain"><td>test2</td></tr>
   <tr><td>2</td></tr>
   <tr><td>2</td></tr>
   <tr><td>2</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Only code is an answer is usually not a good answer. Please explain how this solution solves the problem.